# Best way to store a versioning number (e.g. 1, 1.1, 1.11, 1.11.1) in a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I need to store the success criteria tree of the WCAG in my Rails app: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/

So far, all success criteria have been taken from the WCAG 2.0. Now, some more success criteria were added as WCAG 2.1, and I need to store those, too, and be able to separate them from WCAG 2.0.

So I want to add a `wcag` field to the table, and add the value `2.0` to the existing success criteria. Then I want to add the new success criteria with value `2.1`.

First I wanted to use a normal float, but then I realised that versioning numbers have a different logic:

- For floats this holds true: `1.11 < 1.2`
- For versioning numbers, its the opposite: `1.11 > 1.2`

How can I store this special kind of data in the DB? Preferably while retaining methods like `max` and `min`, and easy ways to compare them with each other (`<`, `>=`, etc.)?

Comment: What db do you use?

Comment: I use the MySQL database.

Comment: For the time being, as there doesn't seem to exist a simple drop-in solution (a gem or similar), I decided to just use a decimal field with `scale: 1`. As WCAG update very slowly, I suspect my app will never run into issues (current version is WCAG `2.1`, it would take many years to go to `2.10`, and probably this will never happen, as version `3.0` would arrive some day before). I added a custom format validation to avoid running into problems, that just prevent the user from trying to enter `2.10` or similar.

Answer (score 3):

Version "numbers" aren't really numbers, they're finite sequences of numbers (i.e they're arrays). So `1.11.6` is really a representation of `[1, 11, 6]`.

If you're using PostgreSQL, then you have access to array columns so you could use an `int[]` column to store them. Break up the strings on input:

```
version_number.split('.').map(&:to_i)
```

and put them back together on output:

```
version_array.join('.')
```

PostgreSQL arrays compare element by element so sorting will work as desired in the database:

```
psql> select array[1,2,3] > array[1,2];
-- True
psql> select array[1,2,3] > array[1,2,5];
-- False
```

---

If you don't have access to array columns then you could left-pad the version components to store them as strings in the database:

```
 '1.2.3'.split('.').map { |s| s.rjust(4, '0') }.join('.')
 # "0001.0002.0003"
```

and the clean them up when you pull them out:

```
'0001.0002.0003'.split('.').map(&:to_i).join('.')
# "1.2.3"
```

Strings like `'0001.0002.0003'` and `'0001.0012'` will sort as desired in the database while still being understandable as-is. The downside is that you'd have to decide how big the components will get so that you can pad the components properly.

---

You might want to wrap all this up in an ActiveRecord concern to hide all the ugliness and string wrangling.

Answer (score 0):

If you use postresql you could use an extension to have a "semver" type (that versioning looks like semver to me, not sure if the follow the specs on the meaning of each version tough).

https://pgxn.org/dist/semver/doc/semver.html

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to make use of the [MYSQL json datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) if you're using ver 8+.

You can run queries on the json parts.